# iOS 11 Files App: How to include files from app bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, wwdc, ios11

I watched the [keynote](https://www.apple.com/apple-events/june-2017/) this year at WWDC and am excited about all the new feature additions being brought to iOS 11. The high importance Apple has placed on games in the App Store and the biggest upgrades in the history of iPad is very exciting. But what was most thriling to me was that iOS 11 will bring for the first time some sibilance of a file system to iOS. They call it the `Files` app, naturally. It seems a big step forward in the new user's getting that same windows-like experience from Microsoft products into iOS.

My question though as a developer currently in development of a project that is heavily document oriented, how am I to be forward looking in my design as so to handle this capability? I know now that Apple allows your app to expose the `documents` directory of your application sandbox to the user via iTunes if you enable this capability in your `.plist` using the `Application supports iTunes file sharing` key. Will this work the same way for the `Files` app? Meaning, will the `Files` app expose the `documents` folder of all the apps on your device that have the `Application supports iTunes file sharing` key set to `YES` in the app's `.plist`?

Comment: Files app will show files from content providers, look for information about content providers, they have been available since iOS 9

Comment: Sorry, it's document providers, not content providers, that's in Android. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/FileProvider.html

Answer (score 3):

Just add `Supports Document Browser` (`UISupportsDocumentBrowser`) key to Info.plist and set it to YES.

The documents folder will be shown in `On My iPhone` section if there are files inside.

Comment: This is wrong. See the docs on UISupportsDocumentBrowser: "Specifies that the app is a document-based app and uses the UIDocumentBrowserViewController class." His app does _not_ use the UIDocumentBrowserViewController class, so he must not turn on this key.

Answer (score 1):

If your app supports iTunes file sharing, and if the *Info.plist* key "Supports opening documents in place" (`LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace`) is also set to `YES`, files in your app's Documents directory will be visible in the Files app. That is safe if you have a UIDocument-based app.